# try-with-resources testing with PowerMockito under static method

Tags: testing, junit, static, powermockito

I will very much appreciate if I get any answer regarding my problem with static method test which holds try-with-resources part of code.

Static method:

```
public class PropertiesUtil {

   public static Properties getProperties() {   
          Properties p = new Properties();        
          File configFile = new File("fileName");

                       <b>try (FileReader pFile = new FileReader(configFile)) {</b>
                              p.load(pFile);
                       } catch (IOException e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                       }
          return p;
   }
}
```

And when I run my test, run-with-resources block makes testing impossible:

```
   @Test
   public void testStatic() {

          PowerMockito.mockStatic(PropertiesUtil.class);
          PowerMockito.when(PropertiesUtil.getProperties()).thenReturn(new Properties());

...
   }
```

I get failure trace:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Inconsistent stackmap frames at branch target 663
Exception Details: 
  Location:
    PropertiesUtil.getProperties()Ljava/util/Properties; @663: aload
  Reason:
    Type 'java/lang/Throwable' (current frame, locals[8]) is not assignable to 'java/lang/Class' (stack map, locals[8])
  Current Frame:
    bci: @653
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'java/util/Properties', top, 'java/lang/Throwable', 'java/lang/Throwable', top, 'java/lang/Throwable', 'java/lang/Throwable', top, 'java/lang/Throwable' }
    stack: { }
  Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @663
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'java/util/Properties', top, 'java/lang/Throwable', top, top, 'java/lang/Throwable', 'java/lang/Throwable', top, 'java/lang/Class' }
    stack: { }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 123d b800 4312 4403 bd00 0312 46b8 004a
    0000010: 124c b800 524b 2a01 3a05 013a 0619 0512
    0000020: 59b8 005b 125c 125d b800 60b8 0064 3a07
    0000030: 1907 b200 56a6 000b b200 563a 06a7 000a
    0000040: 1907 c000 653a 0619 06a5 0008 2ac0 0057
    0000050: b000 0000 0001 3a05 013a 0612 66b8 0060
    0000060: 03bd 0003 1267 b800 68b8 006c 3a07 1907
    0000070: b200 56a5 0032 1907 c100 6e99 0020 b800
    0000080: 7412 75b8 0060 1203 01b6 007b b600 7f01 ...
```

How can I test this with PowerMockito???
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your test method not mocked properly. Below code snippet worked properly.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(PropertiesUtil.class)
public class PropertiesUtilTest {

@Before
public  void setUp() throws Exception{

     Properties mockProps = new Properties();
     mockProps.put("user", "kswaughs");

     PowerMockito.mockStatic(PropertiesUtil.class);
     PowerMockito.when(PropertiesUtil.getProperties()).thenReturn(mockProps);

}

@Test
public void testProps() throws Exception{

      Properties p = PropertiesUtil.getProperties();

      System.out.println("output:"+ p);

  }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> output:{user=kswaughs}

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. But when refactor static method and put regular try-catch block, test becomes green. Problem occures on the line: PowerMockito.mockStatic(PropertiesUtil.class)

Comment: which version of powermockito are u using ? I tested with 1.5.4. Paste your complete test class.

Comment: I added another answer above. And @kswaughs thank you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

- mockito-all - 1.10.19
- powermock-module-junit4 - 1.6.5
- powermock-api-mockito - 1.6.5
- junit - 4.12

  ```
  public class PropertiesUtil {
   private static Properties configProperties;
   public static Properties getConfigProperties() {
      if (configProperties == null) {
          try (InputStream resourceAsStream = PropertiesUtil.class.getClassLoader()
                  .getResourceAsStream("config.properties")) {
              Properties properties = new Properties();
              if (resourceAsStream != null) {
                  properties.load(resourceAsStream);
                  configProperties = properties;
              }
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  return configProperties;
  }
  ```

  ```
  @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
  @PrepareForTest({PropertiesUtil.class})
  public class PropertiesUtilTest {

  @Before
  public void setUp(){

  Properties mockProperties = new Properties();
  mockProperties.setProperty("propertyKey", "propertyValue");

  PowerMockito.mockStatic(PropertiesUtil.class);
      PowerMockito.when(PropertiesUtil.getConfigProperties()).thenReturn(mockProperties);


  }

  @Test
  public void testUtil(){
      Properties prop = PropertiesUtil.getConfigProperties();
      System.err.println(prop);
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this test perfect but what I see is you are not testing PropertiesUtil.getConfigProperties(), you are replacing it's functionality with simply returning "mock". So what are you testing then?